# How do I make a div centred with grid/flex not shrink in width?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid, tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind to center a div in the middle of the page.
When I set flex/grid to justify-start, it doesn't shrink. But when I set justify to center it shrinks and I can't get it to not shrink using flex-shrink-0.

```
  <div className="w-full grid justify-center">
      <div className="flex flex-col max-w-xl border">Content</div>
 </div>
```

How can I make it so the div stays as a fixed width column in the center of the page?

Comment: `max-w-xl` --> `w-xl` ?

Comment: One of the things that I haven't figured out about Tailwind is why I can't set the width to breakpoints. 
I've done that via editing my tailwind config file and it seems to work for now. Thanks for the suggestion, seems to work!